# Java.Lang.NumberFormatException: How to format cursor object to get int value

Tags: android, cursor

I have the following code with me. I am getting a cursor object from the db query, the query actually returns a integer value. I need to get the integer value from the cursor object. I am trying the following method and it is returning an exception. Can any one please let me know how can I get the integer value from the cursor. The query is correct I have tried the same query using some db tools and I  get the required value. Please help me to solve this issue:

My db query:

```
public int getTaskUID(String taskName) {


     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM DataTable WHERE Task_name = ' " +taskName + "'" , null);

       int count = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cursor)) ;
       Log.d("Pana", "the value of count is " + count);

return count;

   }
```

My adb trace:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
03-12 11:23:29.392    1129-1129/com.ms.t.tms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ms.t.tms, PID: 1129
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@59327fe"
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
            at com.ms.t.tms.SQLiteDataBaseAdapter.getTaskUID(SQLiteDataBaseAdapter.java:382)
            at com.ms.t.tms.InsertSubTaskActivity.addUser(InsertSubTaskActivity.java:502)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

My db schema:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
            "(" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TASK_NAME + " VARCHAR(250)," + CONTACT_NAME + " VARCHAR(250)," + CONTACT_NUMBER + " VARCHAR(250),"
            + CONTACT_EMAIL + " VARCHAR(250)," + DESCRIPTION + " VARCHAR(250), " + REMARKS + " VARCHAR(250),"
            + DATE + " VARCHAR(250)," + TIME + " VARCHAR(250)," + ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_DATE + " VARCHAR(250), " + ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME + " VARCHAR(250), "
            + ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE + " VARCHAR(250), " + ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME + " VARCHAR(250), " + NOTIFY_DATE + " VARCHAR(250), " + NOTIFY_TIME + " VARCHAR(250), " +  SUB_TASK_NUMBER + " VARCHAR(250) );";
```

How can I covert the cursor object to int value. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do like this :

```
  int count = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cursor)) ;
  Log.d("Pana", "the value of count is " + count);
```

**Do the following in your code as it is here:**

```
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM DataTable WHERE Task_name = ' " +taskName + "'" , null);

    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount > 0) {
       cursor.moveToFirst()
    }

  long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

Use following code to get value from cursor

```
 // Reading Long Value
 long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

 //Reading String value
 String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("table_column_name"));

 //Reading Double value
 String name = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("table_column_name"));

//Reading Integer value
 String name = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("table_column_name"));
```

To count number of records in a cursor

```
 int count = (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) ? cursor.getCount() : 0;
```

Comment: Yes I tried even this,  this shows cursor Index out of bounds exception.

Comment: I have used 

long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("table_column_name"));

I am getting cursor index out of bounds exception.

Comment: first ensure that you are passing proper column name  to cursor.getColumnIndex() method. that column name must exists in your db table otherwise you will get CursorIndex Out of bounds Exception

Comment: long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

Comment: added my db schema. Please see.

Comment: After moving cursor to first its working. Thanks a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could get value from **Cursor** like

```
 int count = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)) ;
```

### OR

```
 int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("db_column_name"));
```

Comment: I have tried both, both end up in exceptions. Can I please know what mistake am I doing?

Comment: @Kesh1234 You should your cursor at first position. `cursor.moveToFirst();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't covert cursor value to an integer as its a result holder object. You could try to extract the value from cursor and parse it to integer.

Something like:

```
int count = cursor.getCount();//to get number of rows your query gave
```

Or if you want result from request then:

```
int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

Comment: I am getting cursor index out of bounds exception for this.

Comment: For which this? first line or second line?

Comment: after moving cursor to first it worked thanks a lot.